# How to import separate .dat +syntax using Expss in R

Tags: r, expss

How do you import separate .dat +syntax using Expss in R? I see there is a read_spss function, but that requires a .sav file. If you don't have SPSS, the only option I see is to use the opensource Windows software PSPP to manually import .dat +syntax and then save as .sav; but this is a cumbersome solution.

Is there a way to do this with Expss and R using R script?